# Re-enter fullscreen mode after a JavaScript alert call

Tags: javascript

I have this web page that is already in fullscreen mode. Now, when testing with Google Chrome, if I make a call to the `alert` function, the page would quit fullscreen mode.

While I understand that this might be standard behavior, I would still like to make the page re-enter fullscreen mode after quitting it. I now have this function:

```js
function enterFullScreen() {
    let element = document.documentElement;
    if (element.requestFullscreen) {
        element.requestFullscreen();
    }
    else if (element["mozRequestFullScreen"]) {
        element["mozRequestFullScreen"]();
    }
    else if (element["webkitRequestFullscreen"]) {
        element["webkitRequestFullscreen"]();
    }
    else if (element["msRequestFullscreen"]) {
        element["msRequestFullscreen"]();
    }
}
```

It works fine when I run it directly in the console, but when I put it after the `alert` call, believing it would make the page re-enter fullscreen mode, it ceases to work:

```js
elem.onclick = function () {
    alert("something");
    enterFullScreen(); // Nothing happens what-so-ever. No errors either.
}
```

What might be the problem to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The alert probably wasn't fully closed when you re-requested fullscreen. You can simply solve this by setting a timeout without a timeout:

```js
alert("something");
setTimeout(enterFullScreen);
```